# Is it fine that Visual Studio Project Name has periods?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following project:

```
CompanyName.SystemName.ProjectName
```

When used with `Using` it looks like a namespace, But it is not.

Comment: the lats sentence makes little sense. Unless you are aliasing you can only use namespaces in using directives (which I expect you refer to, a using statement would be using(var foo = new bar()...)

And what's your question

Comment: do you want the solution to be named with '.' as separator of words?

Comment: also, `Using` doesn't exist in C#... `using` does, though. Perhaps a concrete example of when this is actually a problem would help? Also, it would help to know if you mean "using directive" vs "using alias" vs "using statement", as they are very different.

Comment: Yes I want the solution to be named with '.' and my question is if it doesnt matter. Also I want to know if someone would hate it or not.

Comment: @TaichiSato why would it matter? Actually, the *solution* name is unrelated and can be anything (as can the project name). If you mean "default namespace" or "the namespaces that happen to be declared in the code", then - again - why would it matter?

Comment: When I want to refer the class under namespace 'Model', if the solution name was 'Project', then I would just have to write 'using Project.Model;' but if the solution name was 'Company.Project.Technology', then I would have to write 'using Company.Project.Technology.Model'. It looks like Model is under a number of namespaces

Comment: I just knew that I can change the default namespace. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can name your projects any way you like as long as it's a valid filename. Usually the project name matches the root namespace of that project but it's not a hard rule.

I prefer to follow that naming convension since it makes it easier to navigate the solution (If I know the name space I know in which project to look) and it's the default in VS. if you wish the default namespace to be different from the project name you will have to change the settings.
ReSharper by default takes it a bit further and enforces a naming convetion for subfolders of a project as well.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, C# uses the same syntax (`.`) to denote:

- namespace traversal
- nested-type traversal (which is actually `+` in the internal type syntax)
- member access (fields/properties/methods/consts/enums/etc)
- as a decimal-point in numeric literals

This is, however, not usually a problem at all...

Answer (score 5):

You claim it's *not* a namespace, but I strongly suspect it *is*. By default, when you create a new class, Visual Studio starts off with a namespace matching the project name and any nested folders. So with a project name of `CompanyName.SystemName.ProjectName` I'd *expect* a new C# file to look something like:

```
using System; // etc

namespace CompanyName.SystemName.ProjectName
{
    public class SomeClass
    {
    }
}
```

At that point, `CompanyName.SystemName.ProjectName` absolutely *is* a namespace, and I'd fully expect a `using` directive along those lines in code trying to use `SomeClass`.

What makes you think it's *not* a namespace?